# Cordova: Touch events on been fired with InAppBrowser plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to catch touch events in my cordova app. cordova app is simple, it's just open a web page inside InAppBrowser.
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_top', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

function loadstartCallback(event) {
      console.log('Loading started: '  + event.url)
    }

```
function loadstopCallback(event) {
  console.log('Loading finished: ' + event.url)
}

function loaderrorCallback(error) {
  console.log('Loading error: ' + error.message)
}

function exitCallback() {
  console.log('Browser is closed...')
}
function touchCallback() {
  alert.log('Touch event..')
}

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);
ref.addEventListener('loadloaderror', loaderrorCallback);
ref.addEventListener('touchstart', touchCallback);
ref.addEventListener('touchmove', touchCallback);
ref.addEventListener('touchend', touchCallback);
ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);
```

All events are working perfect except touchstart, touchmove and touchend event. Any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on the [docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowseraddeventlistener) it doesn't look like the InAppBrowser supports those `touch` events. What you may want to try is using the `executeScript()` method of the InAppBrowser and inject the event listener that way.
2. The second parameter you're passing to `cordova.InAppBrowser.open` looks invalid. InAppBrowser only [support](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen): `_self`, `_blank`, and `system`.